# Create Multindex pandas dataframe from list of objects

Tags: python, pandas, object

Here a sample code to get an object list:

```
import numpy as np

class simpleobj():

    def __init__(self,name):
        self.attr1 = name
        self.attr2 = f"{name}_{np.random.randint(1,100)}"
        self.x= np.random.randint(1,100,size=(100,1))
        self.y1= np.random.randint(1,100,size=(100,1))
        self.y2= np.random.randint(1,100,size=(100,1))

objectlist=[simpleobj(i) for i in list('SAMPLETHINGTOWIRTENOIDEA') ]
```

I want to convert these list of object into a mi-dataframe.
I've always end up with nested arrays in the dataframe... how to reach a multiindexed dataframe like this:

|----indexes----|
attr1 | attr2 | x |  y1 | y2
'S' | 'S50' | 1 | 4     | 3
'S' | 'S50' | 2 | 5  |10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `__dict__` method to pull out attributes of `object` like this, and then you set `multi-index`.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([obj.__dict__ for obj in objectlist]).set_index(['attr1', 'attr2'])
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I also tried this solution. But I failed to use x as an index too.